# Android zoom, drag, draw on ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-canvas, android-bitmap

I have a problem with drawing and zooming ImageView. Help me, please..

When I draw something and then drag or zoom an image - the drawing remains on its place, as you can see on the screencapture. And I need simply to draw on picture, and have possibility to zoom and drag this picture.

[image]
[image]

I have a custom ImageView with this actions:

```
 public class DrawingView extends ImageView {
// onTouch
private float mX, mY;
private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

private Path mPath;

private boolean zoomEnabled = true;

private Paint drawPaint, canvasPaint;
//initial color
private int paintColor = 0xFF660000;
//canvas
private Canvas drawCanvas;
//canvas bitmap
private Bitmap canvasBitmap;

private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;

private float mPosX;
private float mPosY;

private float mLastTouchX;
private float mLastTouchY;
private float mLastGestureX;
private float mLastGestureY;
private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;

public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(getContext(), new ScaleListener());
    setupDrawing();
}

public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
    setupDrawing();
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {

    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    final int action = ev.getAction();
    mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
    if (zoomEnabled) {
        switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                if (!mScaleDetector.isInProgress()) {
                    final float x = ev.getX();
                    final float y = ev.getY();

                    mLastTouchX = x;
                    mLastTouchY = y;
                    mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);
                }
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_1_DOWN: {
                if (mScaleDetector.isInProgress()) {
                    final float gx = mScaleDetector.getFocusX();
                    final float gy = mScaleDetector.getFocusY();
                    mLastGestureX = gx;
                    mLastGestureY = gy;
                }
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {

                // Only move if the ScaleGestureDetector isn't processing a gesture.
                if (!mScaleDetector.isInProgress()) {
                    final int pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
                    final float x = ev.getX(pointerIndex);
                    final float y = ev.getY(pointerIndex);

                    final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
                    final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

                    mPosX += dx;
                    mPosY += dy;

                    invalidate();

                    mLastTouchX = x;
                    mLastTouchY = y;
                } else {
                    final float gx = mScaleDetector.getFocusX();
                    final float gy = mScaleDetector.getFocusY();

                    final float gdx = gx - mLastGestureX;
                    final float gdy = gy - mLastGestureY;

                    mPosX += gdx;
                    mPosY += gdy;

                    invalidate();

                    mLastGestureX = gx;
                    mLastGestureY = gy;
                }

                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {

                final int pointerIndex = (ev.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK)
                        >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
                final int pointerId = ev.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
                if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
                    // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
                    // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
                    final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                    mLastTouchX = ev.getX(newPointerIndex);
                    mLastTouchY = ev.getY(newPointerIndex);
                    mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
                } else {
                    final int tempPointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
                    mLastTouchX = ev.getX(tempPointerIndex);
                    mLastTouchY = ev.getY(tempPointerIndex);
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        return true;
    } else {
        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touchStart(ev.getX(), ev.getY());
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touchMove(ev.getX(), ev.getY());
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touchUp();
                invalidate();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);

    if (mScaleDetector.isInProgress()) {
        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, mScaleDetector.getFocusX(), mScaleDetector.getFocusY());
    }
    else{
        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, mLastGestureX, mLastGestureY);
    }
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();

    canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, drawPaint);
}

private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

        // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
        mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 10.0f));

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}

private void setupDrawing(){
    mPath = new Path();
    drawPaint = new Paint();
    drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
    drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(20);
    drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    canvasPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
}

public void setZoomEnabled(boolean b){
    this.zoomEnabled = b;
}

private void touchStart(float x, float y) {
    // mPath.reset();
    mPath.moveTo(x, y);
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
}

private void touchMove(float x, float y) {
    float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
    if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
        mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }
}

private void touchUp() {
    mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
    // commit the path to our offscreen
    drawCanvas.drawPath(mPath, drawPaint);
    // kill this so we don't double draw
    mPath.reset();
}
```

And activity:

```
 public class DrawActivity extends Activity{

DrawingView image;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.draw);

    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(MyApp.getColorRes(R.color.primary));
    paint.setStrokeWidth(10);

    image = (DrawingView) findViewById(R.id.image);

    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
            getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArray"), 0, getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArray").length);


    Bitmap alteredBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), bmp.getConfig());
    final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(alteredBmp);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, paint);
    image.setImageBitmap(alteredBmp);

    ImageButton paintBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.paint_btn);
    paintBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View button) {
            button.setSelected(!button.isSelected());
            image.setZoomEnabled(!button.isSelected());
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `onDraw()`, you are drawing your path directly using the View's canvas. Instead draw the path on to the `canvasBitmap` via `drawCanvas`. Once this is done, your `canvasBitmap` will contain both the **image** and the **drawing**. Now when you scale or move, both will change appropriately, since they are now in a single bitmap.

Instead of the this:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
canvas.drawPath(mPath, drawPaint);
```

Do something like this:

```
drawCanvas.drawPath(mPath, drawPaint);
canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
```

Comment: Thank you!! You were right! Also I had to put this lines before canvas.restore();

Comment: When i draw on zoomedview it's draw on wrong coordinate how to,solve??

Comment: You can do it in 2 ways. First scale your canvas to 0, then draw, and then scale back to original scale factor. Or, you can scale your coordinate and then draw with that coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

**Here Is the Complete Source Code of Zoom,Drag,Touchable ImageView..
Its Work Smooth While perform Drag and Zoom on Image**.

package com.admin.imagemovementzoom;

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.FloatMath;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;


public class FullmageActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private ImageView img_fullimage;
    private String picturePath;


    private static final String TAG = "Touch";
    // These matrices will be used to move and zoom image
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

    // We can be in one of these 3 states
    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    int mode = NONE;

    // Remember some things for zooming
    PointF start = new PointF();
    PointF mid = new PointF();
    float oldDist = 1f;

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullmage);

        picturePath = getIntent().getStringExtra("image");

        FindId();

        Log.d("adaa", "file://" + picturePath);

        Picasso.get().load("file://" + picturePath).into(img_fullimage);

        img_fullimage.setOnTouchListener(this);
        img_fullimage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);

    }


    private void FindId() {
        img_fullimage = findViewById(R.id.img_full);
    }


    /**
     * Called when a touch event is dispatched to a view. This allows listeners to
     * get a chance to respond before the target view.
     *
     * @param v     The view the touch event has been dispatched to.
     * @param event The MotionEvent object containing full information about
     *              the event.
     * @return True if the listener has consumed the event, false otherwise.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        ImageView view = (ImageView) v;

        // Dump touch event to log
        dumpEvent(event);

        // Handle touch events here...
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG");
                mode = DRAG;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                oldDist = spacing(event);
                Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
                if (oldDist > 10f) {
                    savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                    midPoint(mid, event);
                    mode = ZOOM;
                    Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM");
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                mode = NONE;
                Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (mode == DRAG) {
                    // ...
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x,
                            event.getY() - start.y);
                } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                    float newDist = spacing(event);
                    Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
                    if (newDist > 10f) {
                        matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                        float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                        matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                    }
                }
                break;
        }

        view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
        return true; // indicate event was handled
    }

    /**
     * Show an event in the LogCat view, for debugging
     */
    private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        String names[] = {"DOWN", "UP", "MOVE", "CANCEL", "OUTSIDE",
                "POINTER_DOWN", "POINTER_UP", "7?", "8?", "9?"};
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int action = event.getAction();
        int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
        sb.append("event ACTION_").append(names[actionCode]);
        if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN
                || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {
            sb.append("(pid ").append(
                    action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
            sb.append(")");
        }
        sb.append("[");
        for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) {
            sb.append("#").append(i);
            sb.append("(pid ").append(event.getPointerId(i));
            sb.append(")=").append((int) event.getX(i));
            sb.append(",").append((int) event.getY(i));
            if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())
                sb.append(";");
        }
        sb.append("]");
        Log.d(TAG, sb.toString());
    }

    /**
     * Determine the space between the first two fingers
     */
    private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        return (float) Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    /**
     * Calculate the mid point of the first two fingers
     */
    private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
        point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
    }
}
```